# How to determine the best postcondition in this question?

Tags: java, arrays

1. Consider the following program segment:

```
/** Precondition: a[0]...a[n-1] is an initialized array of integers, and 0 < n <= a.length. **/
int c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  if (a[i] >= 0)
  {
    a[c] = a[i];
    c++;
  }
n = c;
```

Which is the best postcondition for the segment?

1. a[0] to a[n-1] has been stripped of all positive integers.
2. a[0] to a[n-1] has been stripped of all negative integers.
3. a[0] to a[n-1] has been stripped of all nonnegative integers.
4. 4a[0] to a[n-1] has been stripped of all occurrences of zero.
5. The updated value of n is less than or equal to the value of n before execution
   of the segment.

This is a question on the AP CSA exam.  The answer key says that 2. is the answer (it states that 5. is also correct but would not be the "best" postcondition). But I am just thinking: "what if ALL the elements in the initial list are negative numbers?" If that's the case, wouldn't it be impossible to strip away any negative number?

Comment: the postcondition should not be based on code. The postcondition should be known before you start coding, and your code should be based on the pre- and postconditions. For all we know, there is an error in your code, and it doesn't do what it should. How do you expect us to correctly guess what the postcondition should be?

Comment: @michael-mo:  What I would suggest for you is to get a decent Java IDE and step through the code line-by-line to understand how it works for real. This greatly helps in understanding how things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "what if ALL the elements in the initial list are negative numbers?" If that's the case, wouldn't it be impossible to strip away any negative number?

I thought so too at first, but note that the end `n` is updated:

```
n = c
```

With that and only negative numbers `n` would be zero and `a[0] to a[n-1]` would be an empty set, for which the statement *It does not contain negative numbers* is true.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that the algorithm is **changing the array's values in place**, so it really "strips away" negative numbers. It does it by iterating through all elements of array `a` and moving it to a lower index if it's a non-negative number.

Then at the end, it sets `n` to the last index of the element which met the criteria (being non-negative). That's why you have `n = c;` as the last statement.

So **statement 2 is true**. The new size of the array is always smaller or equal to the original, so **statement 5 is also true**.

One thing to notice: In Java, you can still reach all elements if you iterate through the original array. Because in Java every array has a fixed length since being initialized. Let's see the following array:

```
int a[] = {-1,2,3,-4,5,-6,7,8,-9,-10};
```

So if I iterate using `n` at the end, I just get the values that meet the criteria:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
}
```

This will print `2,3,5,7,8`, but if I iterate through `a` I get all the values from the end of the array:

```
for (int e : a) {
    System.out.print(e + ",");
}
```

Now it will print `2,3,5,7,8,-6,7,8,-9,-10`. So this algorithm leaves some garbage behind.